# Program's icon disappears after moving into a folder

Tags: windows-10, icons

By disappears I mean it defaults to the blank white paper icon; happens to both a link and the program itself and they display correctly in other sizes. It didn't happen when I first installed it, suddenly started after a couple restarts and persists even when I restart the computer or reinstall the program. It's happening only with CPU-Z, GPU-Z, HWMonitor, CrystalDiskInfo, CrystalDiskMark and Core Temp.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by changing the icon of the link to something else and then changing it back very slowly (>5s delay between clicks, otherwise the icon goes back to the default blank paper).

Below are my speculations on what could be happening.

Maybe those programs don't have a version of their icon in currently used size, in which case I have no idea why my "fix" helped or why it doesn't work when you do it too fast. Alternatively, I've heard (from a friend) resolution could be an issue - I do have multiple monitors, two 1920x1080 and one 1024x768 - but this didn't occur on my old Windows installation with the same screen setup.

Comment: And now it randomly happened to the icon of WinRar and Notepad++. I am lost.